# Python/MySQL - Export CSV file from DB

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to export a database report in csv, but when generating a new report with new data entered, it does not update when generating.
I created a button to execute the function.
Following is the code below:

```
import pymysql
from pymysql import InternalError
from pathlib import Path
from tkinter import *

tess = Tk()
tess.title("tess")


def exp_rel_emp():

    conn = pymysql.connect(host="localhost", port=3306, user="root", password="", db="omnia")
    print("connect sucessfull!")

    try:
        with conn:
            statm = "SELECT * FROM omniacademp INTO OUTFILE '/TEMP/CadastroEmpresas.CSV' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY ''"
            cursor = conn.cursor()

            with cursor:
                cursor.execute(statm)
                results = cursor.fetchone()
                print(results)
    except InternalError:
        Path('/TEMP/CadastroEmpresas.CSV').touch()
    finally:
        conn.close()
        print("MySQL connection is closed")



bt = Button(tess, text="tess", command=exp_rel_emp)
bt.place(x=10, y=10)


tess.mainloop()
```

Comment: But why are your using fetchone?...probably you need to use fetchall

Comment: even if I change, the same thing happens

Comment: Why are you fetching anything on an action query that exports data to csv file? Is the csv actually generated with data? And are you saying this data is *old* and not *updated*? Where is the update process?